# Using enum values with Chars and integer types in a switch statement in C#

Tags: c#, .net, enums, .net-4.5

So, I was wondering if it is acceptable practice or bad practice to use both integer and character types within an Enum type. For example, I am currently working with a payment processing vendor system. They can call our soap request and send ids for payment types anywhere from 1 to 25 and also can send characters such as C,M, and O.  I wanted to use an enum for clarity in reading the code, but one problem I am having is that I also wanted to sue a switch for this. Is this a bad practice on handling this, also can I handle this safely in a switch or should I just do a if else, and try parse for handling incorrect casting?

Example of Enum values would be the following:

```
internal enum PaymentTypeEnum
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Payment Type Id via Phone from ACI. Note: Int32
    /// </summary>
    PhonePayment_IVR = '9',
    /// <summary>
    /// Payment Type Id via electronic from ACI. Note: Int32
    /// </summary>
    eCollectPayment = '5',
    /// <summary>
    /// Payment Type Id for CANCEL payment. Note: Char
    /// </summary>
    CancelPayment = 'C',
}
```

Comment: Why concerns do you have about using a switch statement?  You can use either the label or the value of the enum.

Comment: This might lead to subtle bugs if one uses `(PaymentTypeEnum)9` instead of `(PaymentTypeEnum)'9'`. I would prefer defining a lookup method or dictionary that makes the `char` type explicit.

Comment: How would this work with a payment type id of `25`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like ludicrous practice to use char members for enumerations, since they are numeric types under the hood.

Want to see how your example compiles?

```
//Your code...
internal enum PaymentTypeEnum
{
    PhonePayment_IVR = '9',
    eCollectPayment = '5',
    CancelPayment = 'C',
}

// Compiled...
internal enum PaymentTypeEnum
{
    PhonePayment_IVR = 57,
    eCollectPayment = 53,
    CancelPayment = 67
}
```

You seem to be missing a level of abstraction. Your enum should represent payment types, then if you need characters to represent each enum member, use a dictionary

```
Dictionary<PaymentTypeEnum, char> types = new Dictionary<PaymentTypeEnum, char>();

types[PaymentTypeEnum.PhonePayment_IVR] = '9';
types[PaymentTypeEnum.eCollectPayment] = '5';
types[PaymentTypeEnum.CancelPayment] = 'C';

public char GetPaymentType(PaymentTypeEnum pt)
{
    if(types.ContainsKey(pt))
    {
        return types[pt];
    }

    return default(char); // assuming (char)0 is meaningless in this context...otherwise...

    throw new InvalidArgumentException(...);
}
```

Also, don't suffix your enum with Enum...you already know it's an enum!

Comment: Iw as also thinking about using dictionary. Thanks, I will do so, and that is why I asked.